# Remove trailing slashes in URLs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to remove all trailing slashes for ALL URLs ending in `.html`. I already have this code which is supposed to remove them for all URLs:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

But I want to apply it only to URLs ending in `.html`, such that:

```
http://example.com/a/b.html/           >   http://example.com/a/b.html
http://www.example.com/ccc.html/////   >   http://www.exaxmple.com/ccc.html
```

Note that for some reason I am seeing multiple slashes at the end of some URLs, and I want these removed in a single redirect.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)(.html)/+$ $1$2 [R=301,L]`